# Making a task list that, when clicking a checkbox, a task fully gets grayed out but having trouble copying the conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

Essentially just as the title says, I'm making a task list with a "Finished" category that has checkboxes. The way I currently have it set up is that, with the conditional formatting, when you hit the checkbox, the entire row gets grayed out as the task has been completed.

Since it's a big list, however, I don't want to have to go through and do the conditional format rule for each and every row as it descends. I thought I could just do the normal drag down thing but when I try to, it doesn't change to the appropriate cell number in the formula that's in the conditional formatting rule.

I've attached some screenshots of what I'm talking about so, if anyone can help me figure out how to do that, that'd be amazing, thank you!

[What the sheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbkX1.png)

[Conditional Formatting Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mup9U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set the range to B3:J100 (or whatever range you want the CF to be applied to) and use as a custom formula

```
=$K3=TRUE
```

This rule should work for all the rows in the dedicated range.